# How to remove repetitive text from a given txt file in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python.
I have a txt file that I have read into pandas df using `pd.read_csv('transactions.txt)`. But it goes like this over 80,000 line (I'm showing 2 lines here):

```
{"accountNumber": "737265056", "customerId": "737265056", "creditLimit": 5000.0, "availableMoney": 5000.0, "transactionDateTime": "2016-08-13T14:27:32", "transactionAmount": 98.55, "merchantName": "Uber", "acqCountry": "US", "merchantCountryCode": "US", "posEntryMode": "02", "posConditionCode": "01", "merchantCategoryCode": "rideshare", "currentExpDate": "06/2023", "accountOpenDate": "2015-03-14", "dateOfLastAddressChange": "2015-03-14", "cardCVV": "414", "enteredCVV": "414", "cardLast4Digits": "1803", "transactionType": "PURCHASE", "echoBuffer": "", "currentBalance": 0.0, "merchantCity": "", "merchantState": "", "merchantZip": "", "cardPresent": false, "posOnPremises": "", "recurringAuthInd": "", "expirationDateKeyInMatch": false, "isFraud": false}

{"accountNumber": "737265056", "customerId": "737265056", "creditLimit": 5000.0, "availableMoney": 5000.0, "transactionDateTime": "2016-10-11T05:05:54", "transactionAmount": 74.51, "merchantName": "AMC #191138", "acqCountry": "US", "merchantCountryCode": "US", "posEntryMode": "09", "posConditionCode": "01", "merchantCategoryCode": "entertainment", "cardPresent": true, "currentExpDate": "02/2024", "accountOpenDate": "2015-03-14", "dateOfLastAddressChange": "2015-03-14", "cardCVV": "486", "enteredCVV": "486", "cardLast4Digits": "767", "transactionType": "PURCHASE", "echoBuffer": "", "currentBalance": 0.0, "merchantCity": "", "merchantState": "", "merchantZip": "", "posOnPremises": "", "recurringAuthInd": "", "expirationDateKeyInMatch": false, "isFraud": false}
```

As you can see, the lines start with `{` and end with `}`

Please help me how to delete the repetitive variable names in every line, and ALSO keep the variable names as column headers.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!! Please update your question with sample expected output

Comment: Is your file _actually_ like this, or does it start with a `[` and end with a `]` and have a `,` at the end of every line? (I think you actually have a JSON array, and not a CSV.)

Comment: Load it as json and create a dataframe using the proper orient

Comment: @MahendraSingh I think OP was clear in their expected output: make JSON keys columns.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include a reproducible code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that this is not a CSV. If it is, it's *very badly formatted* because every line would be only a single column containing a huge JSON payload.

Assuming this is actually a JSON file, read it instead with

```
df = pandas.read_json('file.txt')
```

And you will get your expected output with field-names as columns.

Ref: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html

Answer (score 0):

You can read this file like a normal text file line-by-line, and consider each string as a JSON String, then convert it to a dictionary. Finally combine all the dictionaries into one dictionary, and convert it into a pandas Dataframe.

I am pretty sure this isn't the best solution, but it would atleast work, so if anyone has any improvements please do point out in the comments.

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

data_file = open('transactions.txt', 'r')
list_of_json_dicts = [json.loads(line) for line in data_file]
data_file.close()

keys = list_of_json_dicts[0].keys()

combined_dict = { current_key:[obj[current_key] for obj in list_of_json_dicts] for current_key in keys}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(combined_dict)
```